# How to integrade a group of disconnected smiles descriptors from molecular into a single smiles descriptor?

Tags: molecular-structure, cheminformatics

I am new to cheminfo so this question may sound stupid.

I am trying to calculate the RDF(radial distribution function) of these two compounds below:

https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/155293646

https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/15182658

and I'm using http://www.scbdd.com/chemdes/start/ where it takes SMILES of the compound as an input.

However, I notice that RDF, due to its internal algorithm, can only calculate the descriptor for one single molecule per run, but since mine have several disconnected structures for each molecule, it seems impossible to run.

I wonder if there is some package/website/software for me to preprocess disconnected molecule like those so that I can get a single and continuous SMILES descriptor from it.

Comment: Look into "desalting" modules in rdkit.